# Error finding LCM in javascript with larger numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math, lcm

Currently trying to find LCM using js for a course. It seems to work no problem, but when I submit it I am getting a failed result for input `226553150 1023473145` and that is returning `46374212988031340` when it should be returning `46374212988031350` Thanks for anything you can do!

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
terminal: false
});

function lcm(a,b) {
   return((a*b)/gcd(a,b))
}

function gcd(a,b) {
   if(b == 0){
    return a;
   }
   return gcd(b,(a%b));
}




rl.on('line', (line) => {
  var a = parseInt(line.toString().split(' ')[0]);
  var b = parseInt(line.toString().split(' ')[1]);
  console.log(lcm(a,b));
  rl.close();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the maximum safe integer in JavaScript is [`9007199254740991`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and your result is bigger than that.

Use a [big integer](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=bigint&page=1&ranking=optimal) package to represent large integers.

Comment: I can only submit one file

Comment: Apparently you get the right answer if you calculate LCM like this `a * (b / gcd(a, b))`

Comment: Not odd at all. Changing the order removes the integer overflow.